# Eclipse Indigo Not Hitting Breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse Indigo (3.7.0), with JDK 1.6.0_22, and I am running into an issue.

[image]

In the screenshot above, I set two breakpoints, but then only the breakpoint at line 281 is hitting, not the one at line 274. I tried cleaning my project via Project->Clean, adding -clean to the eclipse.ini file in the Eclipse install directory, restarting my computer, and restarting Eclipse, but they all didn't work. I am running Windows XP Pro SP3.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It will only stop if the blue dot has a hook attached, but neither has? Or what do you see when you start debugging?

Comment: Maybe the compiler took that line of code out during the optimization phase.

Comment: Is that breakpoint visible from the Debug menu? You should be able to bring up a view of all breakpoints and make sure it's checked.

Comment: Hi all, I fixed the problem. The project I'm working on requires the Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse as I just found out that there are some Scala code that I didn't write. The Scala compiler was needed to work in conjunction with the Java compiler, so in the end, the Java code that I was working on wasn't compiling into new bytecode, which is the reason why the breakpoints were not being hit. It's just one of those very rare things that happen.

Comment: Could you write that as an explicit answer and mark that as the right answer? This would allow others of the find a question with an answer, and would show the ones that like to help that help is no more needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The project I'm working on requires the Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse as I just found out that there are some Scala code that I didn't write. The Scala compiler was needed to work in conjunction with the Java compiler, so in the end, the Java code that I was working on wasn't compiling into new bytecode, which is the reason why the breakpoints were not being hit. It's just one of those very rare things that happen.